# I deleted fish shell and now VS Code terminal doesn't work

Tags: bash, terminal, shell, fish

I have been working on a tutorial in Angular.  Everything was working fine before I went to work today.  I came back to my home computer after work today and the fish shell I was using within VS code was not recognizing any commands (commands such as node --version weren't working, but did work in my mac terminal.app).  I don't know why fish wasn't recognizing commands all of a sudden. I've been using it for months. I went online and decided to uninstall fish shell using the advice I found here:

https://fishshell.com/docs/2.0/faq.html

After this, my VS Code terminal doesn't work.  I get this error when trying to open a terminal:

The terminal process failed to launch: Path to shell executable "/usr/local/bin/fish" does not exist.

How can I resolve this issue to use bash as the default terminal?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved this by adding this line to settings.json:

```
"terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.osx": "bash"
```